# operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~* unknown ruby code

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I try to query users in the database when I do a search.
However, I am getting a specific error which is
`operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~* unknown`

In my database, the record of data_of_birth is saved in the format below.
Not sure what I am missing.
Code below

```
field == "dob"
    selected_date = Date.strptime(query, '%Y-%m-%d')
    items = Patient.joins(role: :user).where(
        'users.date_of_birth ILIKE :search', search: "%#{selected_date}%")
```

Here how date_of_birth is saving in the DB

```
 date_of_birth: "1997-03-29 00:00:00"
```

Comment: `ILIKE` on a timestamp doesn't make much sense. You probably just want `=`?

Comment: Shouldn't your `date_of_birth` column have type `date` rather than `timestamp`? Then you could do a simple equality test.

Comment: it has a datetime. My column looks this in the database 't.datetime "date_of_birth", null: false'

Comment: should it just be date instead of datetime? @muistooshort

Comment: Yes, `t.date` would be a better fit. `t.datetime` in a migration ends up as `timestamp` inside PostgreSQL, sorry for the terminology change. You still wouldn't be able to use LIKE in PostgreSQL though, you'd use `=`. SQLite would let you use LIKE because it doesn't have real date or time type, it stores dates and times inside text values using ISO-8601 formats; I don't know if this part applies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Timestamps are stored as numbers in the database, not as strings, so using string comparisons (e.g. `ILIKE`) won't work.

It sounds like you're trying to match timestamps to dates. You can simply cast the timestamp to a date for that. Something like:

```
WHERE users.date_of_birth::date = '2019-06-14'
```

That would seem to translate to the following, based on your code.

```
field == "dob"
        selected_date = Date.strptime(query, '%Y-%m-%d')
        items = Patient.joins(role: :user).where('users.date_of_birth::date = :search', search: "%#{selected_date}%")
```

I'm unfamiliar with the libraries you're using, but it looks like the "::date" part might run into the placeholder functionality. You may need to tinker with that in order for it to work.